# XNA - The name 'ball' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, class, xna, initialization, pong

I'm working on a pong game since I'm pretty new to XNA, and I've ran into a problem...
i have 3 classes, `"Game1.cs"`, `"Ball.cs"`, and `"GreenPaddle.cs"`.

The `GreenPaddle.cs` contains  `Rectangle gpRect`, `Texture2D gPtexture`, `Vector2 position`.

I have movement and such, and in the ball class I have an intersect boolean.
But when i try to initialize it in `game1.cs` i get errors. Here are the classes:

GreenPaddle.cs:

```
public class GreenPaddle
{
    Texture2D gPtexture;
    public Vector2 position;
    public Rectangle gpRect;
    public Vector2 origin;
    public int speed = 2;

    public GreenPaddle()
    {

    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        gPtexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("greenpaddle");
        position = new Vector2(20, 200);
        gpRect = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y,
            gPtexture.Width, gPtexture.Height);
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();

        //Movement
        PaddleMovement();

        //Border Collision
        isCollidingWithBorders();
      }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(gPtexture, position, gpRect, Color.LawnGreen);
    }
    public Boolean isCollidingWithBorders()
    {
        if (position.Y < 83 && gpRect.Y < 83)
        {
            position.Y = 83;
            gpRect.Y = 83;
            return true;
        }

        if (position.Y > 400 && gpRect.Y > 400)
        {
            position.Y = 400;
            gpRect.Y = 400;
            return true;
        }

        else { return false; }

    }

    public void PaddleMovement()
    {
        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            position.Y -= speed;
            gpRect.Y -= speed;
        }
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            position.Y += speed;
            gpRect.Y += speed;
        }
    }
}
```

Ball.cs:

```
public class Ball
{
    GreenPaddle gPaddle;


    Texture2D ballTexture;
    Vector2 ballPosition;
    Rectangle ballRect;
    int speed = 2;
    bool movingUp, movingLeft;

    public Ball(GreenPaddle paddle)
    {
        this.gPaddle = paddle;
        movingLeft = true;
        movingUp = true;
    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        ballTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ball");
        ballPosition = new Vector2(380, 225);
        ballRect = new Rectangle((int)ballPosition.X, (int)ballPosition.Y,
            ballTexture.Width, ballTexture.Height);

    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        BallMovement();

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(ballTexture, ballPosition, ballRect, Color.White);
    }

    public void BallMovement()
    {
        if (movingUp) { ballPosition.Y -= speed; }
        if (!movingUp) { ballPosition.Y += speed; }
        if (movingLeft) { ballPosition.X -= speed; }
        if (!movingLeft) { ballPosition.X += speed; }

        if (ballRect.Intersects(gPaddle.gpRect))
            movingLeft = !movingLeft;
                movingUp = !movingUp;

        if (ballPosition.Y < 85)
        {
            movingUp = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Game1.cs:

```
 public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    GreenPaddle gPaddle = new GreenPaddle();


    Texture2D BackGround;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 500;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {

    Ball ball = new Ball(gPaddle);
        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        BackGround = Content.Load<Texture2D>("pongBG");
        gPaddle.LoadContent(Content);
        //ball.LoadContent(Content);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        gPaddle.Update(gameTime);
        ball.Update(gameTime);//Error Line

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(BackGround, new Vector2(0f, 0f), Color.White);
        gPaddle.Draw(spriteBatch);
        ball.Draw(spriteBatch);//Error Line
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Thats it, I don't know what to do with the initialize part :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look carefully how you initialize your ball, you declare it in the scope of the method (Between the braces).  This means you cannot access it anywhere else, which you are trying to do in the `Update` and `Draw` methods.

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    Ball ball = new Ball(gPaddle);
    base.Initialize();
}
```

Additionally, as soon as the function ends your `Ball` object is deleted.

This can be fixed by putting `Ball ball` into your class scope so that it is available to all members of the class, like so:

```
Ball ball;  //In the class scope

protected override void Initialize()
{
    ball = new Ball(gPaddle);
    base.Initialize();
}
```

If your not familiar with scopes, check out [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx) article (Nothing really good on MSDN)

Comment: Thank you so much for telling me and explaining :)
i HATE when people only gives the final code without further explaining, gj man :DD

Comment: Now i got another error.. :/
in my Game1.cs i get errors on the `gPaddle.Update(gameTime);`
"NullReferenceExecption was unhandled". I'm sorry if im annoying.. :///

Comment: Can you hover over the variables, what is null? `gPaddle`? Because it should be initialized, or is it the code in `gPaddle.Update()`?

Comment: Both the `ball` and `gPaddle` is `Null` :// In the troubleshooting tips it says: **Use the "new" keyword to create an object instance.**
**Check to determine if the object is null before calling the method**
Yup, that's it :/  Tell me if im giving the wrong info lol x)

Comment: I don't see what could possibly be wrong. Just to double check, where are you initializing the `gPaddle` and `ball`?

Comment: `protected override void Initialize()
        {
            GreenPaddle gPaddle = new GreenPaddle();
            Ball ball = new Ball(gPaddle);
        }`
I've also tried in Public Game1()
But NOPE :/

Comment: You didn't make the changes I said in my answer, for both GreenPaddle and Ball you need to move the definition out of the method and into the class. `GreenPaddle gPaddle;` and `Ball ball;` and in initialize `protected override void Initialize() { gPaddle = new GreenPaddle(); ball = new Ball(gPaddle); }`

Comment: Oh sorry, well, got that part up and running now :)

But nows my spriteBatch.Begin(); giving me that nullReferance :o
in the Draw method in Game1.cs i have `gPaddle.Draw(spriteBatch);`
and `ball.Draw(spriteBatch);`

Comment: Your `spriteBatch` is null then. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/tags/spritebatch/info

Comment: @UffePuffe, I don't want to push you into accepting this answer, but I notice none of your questions have accepted answers so I figured I would let you know. You can mark an answer as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark next to the vote buttons.